# How to get author developer link on plugin page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, profiles

When I upload my plugin to Wordpress's repository it currently shows my full name as the author. It doesn't link to my profile though. I've tried changing the author name to my username, but it still doesn't link. How do I link my plugin to my profile on wordpress.org?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your Wordpress.org username in Contributors section in the readme.txt file. Then your plugin will be associated with your account.